# Wait is not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need help on wait function in Selenium webdriver.
I have the following code to wait for "Progressing Pop up" to disappear.
It seems it waits only for some seconds and terminates the script. Please let me know what are the other option?

```
public static void ProcessingData() throws Exception {
    WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait( driver , 180 ); 


    wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='dijitDialogPaneContent']/div/p/b[contains(text()='Processing ...']")));
}
```

Comment: If one of the answers was the solution to your problem, please mark this as complete! :)

Comment: None of these answers are solution for this problem.

Comment: if none of the answers below solve your problem, could you show the html? this could help us.

Answer (score 1):

You placed your timeout on `180`, which is **180 milliseconds**. You probably mean 180 **seconds**? So use `180000`.

Comment: As per the method signature, it takes seconds. Check in the below link: [link](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp                Method signature is:  WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds)

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a closer look at your xpath selector... you are providing

`...b[contains(text()='Processing ...']`

If you know that the text is equal to processing, then you should use

`...b[text()='Processing ...']`.

If you know that the text CONTAINS `Processing ...` then you should use,

`...b[contains(text(), 'Processing ...']`

Comment: according to above, I changed to ...b[text()='Processing ...'], still not working.